# Translation tool for RESX and Excel export / import

Tags: .net, excel, localization, translation, resx

I'm currently working on a project that will be translated into several languages using the RESX file format integrated into Visual Studio / .NET

The translators are sitting in different countries and don't have access to Visual Studio so the best way would be to use Excel to export and import the updated translations (our translators like Excel and know how to use it).

I already tried [Zeta Resource Editor](http://www.zeta-resource-editor.com) and [RESX Manager](http://resxmanager.codeplex.com/) but with both solutions the Excel export doesn't work at all.

Are there any alternatives or recommendations for such tools?

Comment: Professional translators would probably prefer using localization software like [Passolo](http://www.sdl.com/cxc/language/software-localization/passolo/) or [Catalyst](http://www.alchemysoftware.com/products/alchemy_catalyst.html) over using Excel, because these tools allow them to do ID-based matching, translation memory and terminology integration, placeholder handling, and verification. The accepted answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805922/are-resx-files-suitable-for-internationalization?rq=1) is much more concise, in case you are interested in details.

Answer (score 0):

try this, I've written it largely because I was unsatisfied with the solutions out there.  it integrates into VS but can be run standalone:

https://github.com/ekkis/Powershell/blob/master/MT.ps1

you'll need to get a client id from M$ (but they give you 2M words/month translation free - not bad)